# Retrieve Picklist values when using Visualforce Remote Objects

Tags: visualforce, force.com, javascript-remoting, remote-objects

Is there a way to get all Pick list values for a custom field / object using Remote Objects? I have looked at the docs, tried querying the fields but not sure how I can do this. Any guidance or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:remoteObjects>
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Opportunity" fields="Id,Stage"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>

<script>
var result = sforce.connection.describeSObject("Opportunity");

for (var i = 0; i < result.fields.length; i++) {
    if (result.fields[i].name === 'Stage') {
        var field = result.fields[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < field.picklistValues.length; j++) {
            html += '<option value="' + field.picklistValues[j].value + '">' + field.picklistValues[j].value + '</option>';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. This is helpful, and probably the way I will go. However, I read thru Salesforce' docs on VF Remote Objects and was wondering if there is a pure-play Remote Objects based approach. Looks like this is it. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @DevIntern No prob. Since you are using remote objects you can still create them and use the javascript above to populate them with the field values from your picklist. [This](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf) is a good reference for the ajax toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Overide the behavior of standard [retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_overrides.htm) method  .Note the below is untested code but highlights the approach

```
<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="$M">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Account" fields="Name,Type,Phone"
        retrieve="{!$RemoteAction.RemoteObjectContactOverride.retrieve}"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

The apex controller side

```
public class with sharing RemoteObjectContactOverride {

@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, Object> retrieve(String type, Map<String, Object> fields) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Before calling create on: ' + type);

    // Invoke the standard create action
    // For when you want mostly-normal behavior, with a little something different
    Map<String, Object> result = RemoteObjectController.fetchrecords(type, fields);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'After calling create on: ' + type);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Result: ' + result);

    // Here's the little something different, adding extra data to the result
    //Picklist describe your field 

          List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
          Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.Type__c.getDescribe();
         List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
         for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
           options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }     

      //How about serialize here and get JSONresult


    Map<String, Object> customResult = 
        new Map<String, Object> {'custom' => JSONresult };
    customResult.putAll(result);

    return customResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohith. I guess the answer is between JS Remoting and Ajax Toolkit...Although Salesforce docs have nothing on any limitations around retrieving picklist values via Remote Objects, but it may exist anyway.